# Webserver issues, classes not found, failing to unlink cached files

Tags: files, installation

When clearing caches via Drush cr I get

Failed to unlink file 'assets://css/css_4PAeT4dMiadmmD9t_xS9tkg36id2j4imvFUmocQZbdM.css'
which usually means no rights to delete but my system has all admin rights.

Also after installing modules like webform or menu_export I get errors in the logs saying class not found, while the modules are properly install via compose:

InvalidArgumentException: Class ... \Form\MenuExportConfigurationForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of ... \web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php).

Windows 10, tried on: IIS, WAMP and APACHE24 same problems.

php 8.2.13

FRESH DRupal 10.2.3

Comment: drush cr just rebuilds the cache registry and does not fully clear it. Can you try with a full cache clear from UI or maybe try drush eval "drupal_flush_all_caches();"

Comment: If I turn off the aggregate js and css in config the problem goes away so the aggregate function writes files which 'drush cr' can't remove.  Which it should (on my other config it does but I see no differences)